# File Not Found Error while including bits/stdc++.h

Tags: macos, sublimetext

My System: MacOSX 10.9 64-bit

Hey guys, I am working on Sublime Text 3. I have included the `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`
but when I am compiling the source code,

```
adityas-air% g++ 285C.cpp
285C.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'bits/stdc++.h' file not found
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Is there some other header file specific to Mac that is needed to be included instead of this or some tweaking that is needed to be done to Sublime Text 3.Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is distributed with GCC. You install GCC with Macports or Homebrew.

> brew install gcc

Comment: I suppose I downloaded the developer tools for Xcode, after which I was able to compile C++ programs using g++ compiler.

Comment: Xcode does not include gcc but llvm. You can compile C++ programs but you will not have gcc specific files.

Comment: Ok, So I can still install GCC with Homebrew(say) and the issue will be resolved?

Comment: Yes but before doing that: what are you doing?

Comment: Actually I want this for competitive coding, including this header automatically includes all the required headers which otherwise are needed to be explicitly mentioned. Although I can have a template for that but just one header makes code look concise, just that!!

Comment: If you want to distribute what you are doing you should either  include files that will be available or write a configure script to check for what is available

Answer (score 16):

Here are the steps that I followed, if someone is still looking for an answer.

- `brew install gcc`
- `gcc --version`
- cd to InstalledDir path:

  1. `cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include`
- create bits directory in there. use sudo if permission issues

  1. `sudo mkdir bits`
- copy [`stdc++.h` link](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/precompiled/stdc%2B%2B.h) in bits directory, in my case I downloaded it in Downloads.

  1. `cd bits`
  2. `sudo cp ~/Downloads/stdc++.h stdc++.h`

This was enough for the compiling.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Don't know how other answer got accepted.

Comment: I also needed to comment out some lines, namely:

// #include <cstdalign>
//#include <cuchar>
// #include <memory_resource>

Answer (score 12):

Since, bits/stdc++ is a GNU GCC extension, whereas OSX uses the clang compiler.

You have to create **bits** directory inside **/usr/local/include** and then make a header file **stdc++.h** inside bits and paste the contents of this [code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/precompiled/stdc%2B%2B.h) inside it. Then, it should compile as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Did this

```
{
"cmd": ["/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/g++-6", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/g++-6 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
    }
]
}
```

after doing `brew install gcc` and it's working. The g++-6 is the version of the compiler that gets installed, it may be different for different users. Thank you!

Comment: `g++-10 file.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

gcc installation is currently not supported in homebrew on M1/M2 Macs.
Meaning it'll seem like the installation is completed. but then compilation will fail

See experimental solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731799

Answer (score 0):

After steps sited by [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)
Pour cmake projects (OSX) Added this line to your CMakeLists.txt:

*include_directories(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include)*

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the updation of clang. Due to this, a new folder for the new version will be created in the clang folder. The clang folder is present at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang`. Copy the `bits` folder containing the `stdc++.h` file from the previous version folder to the new updated version folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need to add the file `stdc++.h` once we have installed gcc.

This is the way I installed gcc and fixed this problem:

1. Install gcc using `brew install gcc`
2. Go to the path where gcc is installed and check if you have everything in place and also ensure to check the version of g++ present. For me, the path is `/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/bin`. There you will find multiple versions of clang and g++.
3. Now you can hard link your installed g++ version, so that the system uses gcc instead of clang.
   `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/bin/g++-13 /usr/local/bin/g++`
   (I have got g++-13 for me, you might want to check your version.)
4. Compile and check if everything is working and have fun : )
   `g++ -o test_file test_file.cpp`